# Silverlight policy server on custom port?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, cross-domain-policy, policy-server

By default silverlight checks for cross domain policy on port 943. You can also change the **SocketClientAccessPolicyProtocol** property of the **SocketAsyncEventArgs** to check using HTTP on port 80.

I have an in-browser silverlight app and am in a situation where I have to force the policy check to be done using another port. Something above 1023.

**Is there anyway I can force Silverlight to check for cross domain policy on a port different than the default?**

Comment: Why can your policy not be serves on port 80, as that's where the silverlight is coming from, or do you not have access to the root?

And as far as I've found, it's 80 or 943.

Comment: I don't have root access

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different port as long as that BECOMES the root of your web [MS article about all things HTTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838250%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You could host your website on a different port: http://www.myweb.com:8080 as long as the 8080 is the root of your web and your clientaccesspolicy.xml is there.

Search the link for this text "Cross-Domain Communication by using a Client access Policy File" and it should show more examples of what I mean.

You cannot however, host your silverlight plugin on http://www.myweb.com and have the clientaccesspolicy served from http://www.myweb.com:8080/clientaccesspolicy.xml.

You can host http://www.myweb.com and serve the policy from port 943, but you'd have to create a policy listener, and then it's not quite as simple.

Here is a post I did regarding your own policy listener (to host Silverlight in WPF), it may help: [Silverlight Policy Listener/Service host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331727/how-can-i-host-a-silverlight-4-application-in-a-wpf-4-application/10148940#10148940)