# clientaccesspolicy.xml suddenly stopped working

Tags: asp.net, web-services, silverlight, iis-7, clientaccesspolicy.xml

Good afternoon.  I'm in a bit of a pickle.  I tried to help a coworker and now her web application (hosted locally, so I can't show results to you) is not working.  I was trying to edit her clientaccesspolicy.xml file and all was going well.  Then suddenly, every request -- even if I set `domain uri="*"` -- is getting the System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException about cross-domain requests.  Here is the clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <access-policy>
        <cross-domain-access>
            <policy>
                <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
                    <domain uri="*"/>
                </allow-from>
                <grant-to>
                    <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
                </grant-to>
            </policy>
        </cross-domain-access>
    </access-policy>
```

Clearly, the policy is accessible via web: http://gis.co.frederick.va.us/clientaccesspolicy.xml.

What happened?  Where did I go wrong?  I've tried even restarting IIS -- no love.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Use fiddler first to explore more

Comment: How about more strange information?  It is now working intermittently.  From outside our network, it doesn't work at all.  From inside, it works intermittently.  From outside via VPN, it appears to work as expected.

Comment: @SalientBrain : I'm not sure how I would do that.  I have checked in Chrome dev tools and I don't see any errors there.

Comment: possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783086/cross-domain-policy-file-over-net-tcp-for-wcf-servicehost-and-silverlight-5