# Silverlight not finding clientaccesspolicy.xml in Owin self hosted Web Api

Tags: silverlight-5.0, owin, asp.net-web-api2

I am aware of the hundreds of similar questions about Silverlight and the clientaccesspolicy.xml but I am losing my head here. I've gone through almost all the posts on Stackoverflow, tried most of the suggestions and I'm still stuck.

I have a SL client calling a method in an Owin self-hosted web api. I've simplified my api service to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api) example, so there is no unnecessary complexity involved. My api is running on port 9000 for this example.

**The problem** is that I get a 404 error when calling the method in the api. Using Fiddler I can tell that it's not finding the clientaccesspolicy.xml. I've copied the xml file (and crossdomain.xml) to all locations I can think of, and to that of what other posts have suggested.

[image]

Can anyone point out my error or help me in the right direction? Here are some snippets:

clientaccesspolicy.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
  <cross-domain-access>
    <policy>
      <allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">
         <domain uri="http://*"/>        
         <domain uri="https://*"/>
      </allow-from>
      <grant-to>
        <socket-resource port="9000" protocol="tcp" />
        <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
      </grant-to>
    </policy>
  </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:9000/";

        Console.WriteLine("Connected..");
        var server = WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting..");
        server.Dispose();

    }
```

Service Agent in SL:

```
public async Task TestApi()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();                

            var response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:9000/api/test");
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            ... bla bla bla
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }            
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using self hosting you will have to serve the policy file yourself by listening for the request for the policy and passing back the policy file.

See: [Cross domain policy file over net.tcp for WCF servicehost and Silverlight 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783086/cross-domain-policy-file-over-net-tcp-for-wcf-servicehost-and-silverlight-5)

Comment: Thanks, Erno. It took me quite a bit of research but I eventually figured out what is required.