# Combining an HttpListener service and a Wcf service

Tags: wcf, web-services, http

I'm building a self-hosted service to be consumed by Silverlight. This service is not a straight Wcf service, but it uses HttpListener to implement a streaming service for Silverligt. To mkae it accessible by Silverlight, I've created another service (that is a Wcf service) to serve the clientaccesspolicy.xml file.

My problem is that once my clientaccesspolicy service is registered at `http://localhost:9001` I cannot access my streaming service that is listening at `http://localhost:9001/silverlightstream`.

I've a couple of other Wcf services registered at `http://localhost:9001/xxx` which can seamlessly coexist with the clientaccesspolicy service.

What do I need to do to get the streaming service to work together with the clientaccesspolicy service?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a similar question before, I don't know how much it fits your situation, but it does look like it might help you out a little:

[How can I host a Silverlight 4 application in a WPF 4 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331727/how-can-i-host-a-silverlight-4-application-in-a-wpf-4-application/10148940#10148940)

In my project, I took it further and delivered the html/xap files via said self hosted service (so as not to require IIS, as IIS was a bit too much bloat for what I required).